# How to find the icon for installed ssms

Tags: sql-server

I have Installed Sql Server 2014 Express edition and downloaded the Sql server 2014 database.  I cannot find an Icon for the Sql Server on my Desktop to start the Sql program. There is only an icon for the Server Installation Center.  How do I start the Sql server.

Comment: which is your OS and its version?

Comment: >>>How do I start the Sql server<<< To start SQL Server you can use Services or Configuration Manager. Starting SSMS has nothing to do with starting server. Please update your post with the picture of Services, it may be you did not install any server at all

Comment: Check your program files to be sure - mine is in _C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio_. But Express edition usually doesn't include the client tools so you'll have to download them. Google `SSMS installation` to download and install

Comment: Do you want to start the server or start the client tools to type SQL statements into?

Comment: You're an intern. Ask the people who should be training / guiding you. That is the WHOLE idea behind an internship - to learn things from those with more experience.